# React Native useEffect works on file save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, voximplant

I am developing a video chat app using `react-native-voximplant`, everything works, but when the app loads first time, the `login` functionality is happening inside the `useEffect`. So, the problem is, when my `HomeScreen` mounts, the useEffects' should fire and I should get logged in voximplant sdk and now if I tap on call icon, the following is shown in the console:

When HomeScreen mounts:

```js
LOG Client: emit: no handlers for event: AuthResult
LOG Error while trying to login to voximplant:  {"code": 491, "name": "AuthResult", "result": false}
LOG Client: emit: no handlers for event: ConnectionEstablished
```

Now when I tap on call to make a call:

```js
// after a second...

WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
"NOT_LOGGED_IN"
```

**Now when I hit save (ctrl+s)**, I get logged in and now if I make a call, it works! I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Is something wrong with `useEffect` or I'm doing something wrong?

The HomeScreen code:

```js
import {Voximplant} from 'react-native-voximplant';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();

  useEffect(() => {
    const signInToVoximplant = async () => {
      try {
        const fqUsername = '...'; // credentials are correct, don't worry about them.
        const password = '...';
        await voximplant.login(fqUsername, password);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while trying to login to voximplant: ', error);
      }
    };
    signInToVoximplant();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const connect = async () => {
      const status = await voximplant.getClientState();
      if (status === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
        await voximplant.connect();
      } else if (status === Voximplant.ClientState.LOGGED_IN) {
        console.log('[INFO] VOXIMPLANT CONNECTED');
        return;
      }
    };
      connect();
    }, []);
  }
  
  return ...
```

The `call` will only work if I hit `ctrl+s` i.e. save the file, otherwise it will throw `Unhandled Promise rejection...` because it is not logged in, however I have written/provided the login inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: why do you have `await voximplant.login(fqUsername, password);` within a `useEffect`?

Comment: @Sangeet Agarwal because I'm already signing in the user using a different method, now after the user has logged in, i want to anonymously login the voximplant, so that is why, when the home component mounts, the first thing should be to login into voximplant without them knowing (because he already logged in using different method). Actually I'm trying to integrate voximplant SDK into an old project in which authentication is done using node/express backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logs, when the application starts, login is failed with 491 error that means that the client is in invalid state. It happens because you invoke login API before the connection the Voximplant Cloud is established (connect API).

When the app is reloaded, native code is not reinitialised (but js does) and actually the client is still connected to the Voximplant Cloud, that's why login is successful the second time.

To fix the issue, you need to change the order of Voximplant SDK API invocation: first call Client.connect API and then Client.login.

It is also better to move connect/login to the a single useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

- Both useEffect is run on mounted, but ¿whichone first?.
- Try put both functions in the same useEffect, and call them in order:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const signInToVoximplant = async () => {
      ...
    };

    const connect = async () => {
      ...
    };

    signInToVoximplant();
    connect();
}, []);
```

Comment: Same thing, even the useEffect runs on mount, it shows "NOT_LOGGED_IN" when I try to call but if I `ctrl+s` now, it will start working. Why is it happening?